# Parallel.Invoke vs Parallel.Foreach for running parallel process on large list

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach, parallel.invoke

I have C# list which contains around 8000 items (file paths). I want to run a method on all of these items in parallel. For this i have below 2 options:

**1) Manually divide list into small-small chunks (say of 500 size each) and create array of actions for these small lists and then call Parallel.Invoke like below:**

```
    var partitionedLists = MainList.DivideIntoChunks(500);
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    foreach (var lst in partitionedLists)
    {
      actions.Add(() => CallMethod(lst));
    }
    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray())
```

**2) Second option is to run Parallel.ForEach like below**

```
Parallel.ForEach(MainList, item => { CallMethod(item) });
```

- What will the best option here?
- How Parallel.Foreach divide the list
  into small chunks?

Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also use the `AsParallel` LinQ extension method ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950320/17034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is a form of `task-parallelism`, in which you divide your task into group of sub-tasks and execute them in parallel. As is obvious from the code you provided, you are responsible for choosing the level of granularity [chunks] while creating the sub-tasks. The selected granularity might be too big or too low, if one does not rely on appropriate heuristics, and the resulting performance gain might not be significant. `Task-parallelism` is used in scenarios where the operation to be performed takes similar time for all input values.

The second option is a form of `data-parallelism`, in which the input data is divided into smaller chunks based on the number of hardware threads/cores/processors available, and then each individual chunk is processed in isolation. In this case, the .NET library chooses the right level of granularity for you and ensures better CPU utilization. Conventionally, `data-parallelism` is used in scenarios when the operation to be performed can vary in terms of time taken, depending on the input value.

In conclusion, if your operation is more or less uniform over the range of input values and you ***know*** the right granularity [chunk size], go ahead with the first option. If however that's not the case or if you are unsure about the above questions, go with the second option which usually pans out better in most scenarios.

**NOTE**: If this is a very performance critical component of your application, I will advise bench-marking the performances in production like environment with both approaches to get more data, in addition to the above recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is preferable:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Partitioner<Item> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(MainList);

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, item =>
{
    CallMethod(item);
});
```

The main advantage is that in case the `CallMethod` fails for an `item`, the parallel operation will complete as soon as possible. You won't have to wait for all items in the `MainList` to be invoked, before getting the exception. On the contrary The [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke) invokes invariably all the actions.

The [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) is useful if you want to process the `MainList` in roughly ascending order. Alternatively you can pass the `MainList` directly as the source of the `Parallel.ForEach`, in which case the order of execution will be a bit chaotic. The default partitioning for `List<T>`s is [*range partitioning*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning), meaning that each worker thread will be assigned a different large range of the list, and process incrementally this range. With the `Partitioner.Create` you get *chunk partitioning*. This means that each worker thread grabs a small chunk of items from the list, processes them, and then comes back to retrieve the next chunk etc.